# Unused web sockets requests in flutter network activity with almost same time as other http requests

Tags: flutter, debugging, websocket

I was going through my network activity in flutter dev tools. And I noticed that there were some web sockets requests being sent. I have programmed both the backend and the app. And I haven't used web sockets in anyway. All are plain http requests. And the weird thing is I own the IP address where the web sockets are being sent to. Here is the screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

**I am not sending or upgrading to web sockets.** How to know who is sending this request? And why are there extra requests being sent?

Here is the call to authenticate for example:

```dart
Future<UserType> authenticate(User user) async {
  final _log = Logger('authenticate');

  _log.info('authenticating user');
  final response = await http.post(
    base_url + '/authenticate',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: jsonEncode({
      'phone_number': user.phoneNumber.trim(),
      'password': user.password.trim(),
      // notification is a singleton somewhere with a string token 
      'fcm_token': notification.token,
    }),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the POST http call is being upgraded to websocket each time you call the API, look into headers on both sides (default ones or the ones you are passing), 101 response is switching protocol response, as mentioned connection is being upgraded on request by the client
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/101

remove these headers Upgrade: WebSocket and Connection: Upgrade

Comment: I know 101. I am just setting the content type to json in post calls

Comment: The problem is I am not upgrading the calls in anyway.

Comment: I am not adding those headers in the first place!!!!!

Comment: I added my authentication function